# How to stop a timer by fulfilling two conditions of a hitTestObject situation

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anybody please tell me how I can stop a timer by fulfilling two conditions:

1. All objects on stage should hit their `TestObjects`
2. Only when the last object hits its test object the timer will stop.

The player drags and drops movie clips scattered on the stage into its correct position, in a particular order, as in an alphabet learning game, and when the last alphabet is dropped into its appropriate place, the timer stops.

I tried several approaches including the "&&" approach but it does not seem to work.

I am new to **as3**, so please don't answer using the **Object Oriented Programming method**.

Comment: set counter to be equal to the number of objects, when object will hit the "TestObject" reduce the counter, once counter equals 0 stop timer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to check every frame if the objects are in the correct position and them stopping the timer:

```
var objects:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();

private function onEnterFrame(ev:Event):void {
   //check positions of objets
   var allObjectsOK:Boolean = true;
   for each( var do:DisplayObject in objects ) {
       //check if do is in place by checking its x and y properties
       // in this exampel, if x and y are above 10, object is not in place
       if (do.x > 10 && do.y > 10) {
            allObjectsOK = false;
       }
   }

   if (allObjectsOK) {
       timer.stop();
   }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
```

Comment: Jotakun can u please elaborate on your code and be more detailed...what am i supposed to fill in the Boolean = ....; area. I am really new to as3 and hence not able to understand your code...thnx a lot for helping.

Comment: I've updated the code with an example of how to check if objects are in place (checking its properties x and y). You'll have to populate vector objects with the objects you want to check when creating them.

Comment: You could change `if (do.x > 10 && do.y > 10)` to do a collision test with some other object, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and drive this via a mouseUP, seeing as that will always have to happen when you stop dragging. Possibly something like this:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10000, 1);

var alphabetMembers:Array = [letterA,
                             letterB,
                             letterC,
                             //Stick the rest of your letter vars in here
                             ]

var correctLocations:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

correctLocations[letterA] = hitTestA;
correctLocations[letterB] = hitTestB;

//do the same for each character

timer.start();

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp, true);

function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var correctLocation:uint = 0;

    for(var i:int = 0; i < alphabetMembers.length; i++)
    {
        if(alphabetMembers[i].hitTestObject(correctLocations[alphabetMembers[i]]))
        {
            correctLocation++;
        }
    }

    if(correctLocation >= alphabetMembers.length)
    {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glitcher thx for the prompt reply.Can u pls explain some lines. Why,const X_MARGIN:Number = 10;
const Y_MARGIN:Number = 10;

Comment: Glitcher thx for the prompt reply.Can u pls explain some lines. Why,  const X_MARGIN:Number = 10; const Y_MARGIN:Number = 10; Why..onMouseUp true.Why, Dictionary. I would like to benefit more frm ur code, hence the request for more explanation.

Comment: Hi, The X_MARGIN and Y_MARGIN stuff was left in from my first attempt (didn't notice you'd specified hit test) so you can ignore them

Comment: the reason the EventListener call has true for the capture argument is so that all "MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP" events get captured, not just the ones emanating from the document itself. That basically means you don't have to add a listener to every single letter.

The Dictionary lets you link objects like your letters, to other variables by using the object itself as the index or key. What I'm doing in there is linking the letter symbol, with that symbols hit test symbol (I have assumed that's how you're doing it)

Comment: my situation is more complicated than what i supposed it to be...when MC_x.y (it is having a movieclip within it) hits MC_z, whose alpha was zero (so many things happen). MC_x.visible = false...MC_z.alpha = 1 and then scaling and so on...i think it was the ".visible = 0;" tht was the real culprit..

Comment: since the MC_x started becoming invisible one after the other, the "if" statement did not work...that is "if" all the MC_x objects hits MC_z objects..."then", the myTimer should stop..

Comment: anyhow these discussion sessions were really illuminating & i really thank all the contributors...i am going to make a note of all these suggestions and study them further build upon my knowledge of as3...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to have the target location for each MovieClip stored as a property on the piece. (Assuming you are using MovieClips which are dynamic, so you can add a property to them)

Each frame or however often you want to test for this situation just loop through the movieclips and check if the x,y of each MovieClip matches the targetX and targetY that you created on the MovieClip.

for example :

```
public function areWeDoneYet():Boolean
{

     for (var index:int = 0;index < container.numChildren;index++)
     {
         var curLetter:MovieClip = container.getChildAt(index) as MovieClip;

         // test if the curLetter is at target location or close enough for your needs
        // if not return false

     }
     return true; // return true if the loop completed 

     // if it did complete, it means all MovieClips are in right target location.

}
```

So each frame or whenever you want to check you can go :

```
if (areWeDoneYet())
{
    // do whatever you need to do.
    // stop the timer or whatever
}
```

This solution assumes that all your letters are children of a container MovieClip. You could utilize the same concept with an array containing those MovieClips and iterating through that instead.